# Getting NullReferenceException in a C# App and cant see reason why dereference is null

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, windows

i have written simple code that for some particular reason is not working due to getting NullReferenceException of reasons i dont know.

Here is the simple application

```
namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        private string[] IPToCheck;
        private List<string> IPRange;
        private bool CorrectNetwork = false;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            var hostnames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
            foreach (var hn in hostnames)
            {
                if (hn.IPInformation != null &&
                   (hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 71
                   || hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 6))
                {
                    IPToCheck = hn.DisplayName.Split(new char[] { '.' });
                    if (IPToCheck.Count() == 4)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Correct");
                        CorrectNetwork = true;
                    }
                    if (CorrectNetwork)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("{0}.{1}.{2}.",IPToCheck);
                        GenerateIPs(IPToCheck);
                        break;                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void GenerateIPs(string[] IPToCheck)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(IPToCheck[0] + "." + IPToCheck[1] + "." + IPToCheck[2] + "." + i.ToString());
                IPRange.Add(IPToCheck[0] + "." + IPToCheck[1] + "." + IPToCheck[2] + "." + i.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running this i get the following output:

```
Correct
192.168.10.
192.168.10.0
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App1.Windows.exe
```

It highlights:

```
IPRange.Add(IPToCheck[0] + "." + IPToCheck[1] + "." + IPToCheck[2] + "." + i.ToString());
```

It seems that the first "ip" is getting generated in the for loop in the GenerateIPs method.

Why is this NullReferenceException happening? Thanks!

Comment: If that's the line which gets highlighted, but the debug line before is working without exception, it can just be `IPRange`, that is null, or not?

Comment: That is absolutly right. I forgot to add this.IPRange = new List<string>(); as Jurgen Camilleri answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add:

```
this.IPRange = new List<string>();
```

in your `MainPage` constructor.

Comment: How embarrasing, i think i need to take a break! Thanks!

Comment: Happens to all of us sometime or another :)